# Bash: Delete files starting with a certain string

Tags: bash, shell

I get a list of blobs from a storage account and I want to delete the file that they don't starts with mf, I have the next command:

```
blob=$(az storage blob list -c '$web' --account-name "$SA_NAME" --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)
prefix="mf"
for b in $blob
do
  if [[ "$blob" == "$prefix"* ]];
  then
    echo "file $b: is not deleted"
  else
    echo "file $b: is deleted"
  fi
  
done
```

I get the following output where it deletes all files including the ones that start with mf:

```
file assets/fonts/Brevia-SemiboldItalic.ttf: is deleted
file assets/fonts/Brevia-SemiboldItalic.woff: is deleted
file assets/locales/es.json: is deleted
file assets/microapp-dev.json: is deleted
file assets/microapp-local.json: is deleted
file assets/microapp.json: is deleted
file favicon.ico: is deleted
file main.js: is deleted
file main.js.map: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/1.89801b3a85a55b24.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/181.66ff660a1257fc84.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/197.596dd9d1162203a2.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/340.c07e82cc376fa4c7.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/3rdpartylicenses.txt: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/471.deda3ccf16192f26.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/529.c3fdd0c3260c48da.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/650.48ddcd2f364e73da.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/797.8d193779021f0a0b.js: is deleted
file mf/angular-mfe/895.a91f2f017e309e9d.js: is deleted
```

Comment: Typo: `"$blob"` should be `"$b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change the condition in your `if` statement to compare each blob name `$b` against the prefix instead of comparing the entire list of blob names `$blob` against the prefix

something like this :

```
blob=$(az storage blob list -c '$web' --account-name "$SA_NAME" --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)
prefix="mf"
for b in $blob
do
  if [[ "$b" == "$prefix"* ]];
  then
    echo "file $b: is not deleted"
  else
    echo "file $b: is deleted"
    # Delete the blob
    az storage blob delete -c '$web' --account-name "$SA_NAME" -n "$b"
  fi
done
```

the example of result:

```
file mf/file1.txt: is not deleted
file file2.txt: is deleted
file mf/file3.txt: is not deleted
file file4.txt: is deleted
```